# SQL - How do I SUM a GROUP BY recordset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregation

I'm not that strong on SQL, and need some helping figuring out how to get a tally for figures returned in a recordset.

This is how far I've gotten with the query so far:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate()) AS age_in_months, count(email) AS number_of_valid_emails
FROM #result2
WHERE originalretaildate BETWEEN '20140415' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate())
ORDER BY 1
```

This gives me the following results:

```
age_in_months       number_of_valid_emails
-----------------------------
0                   63
1                   2066
2                   1528
3                   2449
4                   1882
5                   1835
6                   1772
7                   2190
8                   2321
9                   2172
10                  2635
11                  1336
12                  601
```

What I need to get is a sum (total) for all those figures. I'd be happy to have it at the bottom, or even just as a single figure returned.

So something like this:

```
age_in_months       number_of_valid_emails
-----------------------------
0                   63
1                   2066
...                 ...
SUM                 2129
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

It's getting there, my SQL query now looks like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate()) AS age_in_months,
count(email) AS number_of_valid_emails
FROM #result2
WHERE originalretaildate BETWEEN '20140415' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate()) WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

This gives me this:

```
0   65
--------
12  598
11  1329
2   1530
6   1777
5   1830
4   1875
1   2049
9   2176
7   2200
8   2319
3   2442
10  2631
NULL    22821
```

My problem now is that it says 'NULL' in the last row. Any ideas how to fix this, so it says something like 'Total' or 'Sum'?

Comment: How about something like `WITH ( <your query> ) AS Q1 SELECT * FROM Q1 UNION ALL SELECT 'SUM', SUM(number_of_valid_emails) FROM Q1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to sum up values at the bottom. you can use rollup to get sum of values at the bottom.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate()) AS age_in_months,
count(email) AS number_of_valid_emails
FROM #result2
WHERE originalretaildate BETWEEN '20140415' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate()) with rollup
ORDER BY 1
```

it will produce output like bellow. at the bottom with sum of all values

```
age_in_months       number_of_valid_emails
-----------------------------
0                   63
1                   2066
2                   1528
3                   2449
4                   1882
5                   1835
6                   1772
7                   2190
8                   2321
9                   2172
10                  2635
11                  1336
12                  601
```

---

```
null                22850
```

**EDIT 1**

as per your edit you can do it using `COALESCE` like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate()),'Total') AS age_in_months,
count(email) AS number_of_valid_emails
FROM #result2
WHERE originalretaildate BETWEEN '20140415' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate()) with rollup
ORDER BY 1
```

**EDIT 2**

use cast to your monthnumber and then use `coalesce()` function so it will be able to cast it in proper way

```
 cast(DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate()) as nvarchar(10))
```

the whole query will go like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(cast(DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate()) as nvarchar(10)),'Total') AS age_in_months,
count(email) AS number_of_valid_emails
FROM #result2
WHERE originalretaildate BETWEEN '20140415' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(m, originalretaildate, getdate()) with rollup
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: once you `ORDER BY 1`, `NULL` will come up at the top. you can use `ORDER BY  (age_in_months * -1) DESC` for ordering

Comment: That's it, you're a prince amoungst men Ameya. I wish I knew SQL like that, so useful.